# Why does IE7 & IE8 ignore my coding for .widget class in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have been css coding for my theme that is based off from Twenty Eleven. Everything looks fine except in IE7 & IE8.

I realized that in those two mentioned browsers, my styling for the widget class ".widget" is ignored. I figured this out after doing an elimination test. Every other class that I have tested takes in the css adjustments. Only those made to .widget is not taken in by IE7 & 8.

Is there a known solution to this?

Extra information: I want the each widget to be contained within a box by implementing black borders of 1px.

Comment: do you have class something like this: `<div class="cl_1 cl_2">...</div>` - 2 or more class in the same div or other tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Scott and @misczu for the help.

I did major elimination testing and found out that it is a HTML5 issue. IE7 & 8 cannot read the new HTML5 elements and it seems my earlier outsource neglected to include the HTML5 js compatibility file. IE7 & 8 wasn't able to process the 'aside' element for which the widgets were contained in.

In the end I had to retrieve the HTML5 compatibility code from Google SVN; the one included in an outdated version of Twenty Eleven was quirky. It works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's impossible to say for sure, but as miszczu commented already, older version of IE have trouble applying rules with multiple classes, like so:

```
.widget { background: red; }
.widget.blue { background: blue; }
```

In most browsers, if you had `<div class="widget blue">test</div>`, it would be blue. But in older IEs, it will still be red, because it doesn't know how to handle the multiple classes.

If this doesn't apply to you, perhaps you could edit your question with more details -- a link to your site or a jsfiddle with the problem would be greatly helpful to solving your problem.